# Reflexive sheaves on stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $C$ be a stable curve over an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic and $\mathcal{F}$ be a reflexive sheaf on $C$. Is $\mathcal{F}$ locally free?

**EDIT** Is the projective dimension of $\mathcal{F}$  less than or equal to $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently: is every f.g. reflexive module $M$ over  $R=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ projective? The answer is no: let $M = R/xR$, then ${\rm Hom}_R(M, R) = \{f\in R\,:xf=0\} = yR \cong M$. Thus $M$ is reflexive, but is not projective.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have added another question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: The $R$-module $M$ in Piotr's answer has infinite projective dimension, with a resolution
$$\ldots R \xrightarrow{\times\, x}R\xrightarrow{\times\, y}R \xrightarrow{\times\, x}R\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0\ .$$